# How to pass arguments to eslint when using nx lint

Tags: eslint, nrwl-nx

I want to use eslint arguments such as `--no-error-on-unmatched-pattern`.

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#options

However, when using `nx lint`/`nx run-many --all --target=lint`/`nx affected:lint` - these arguments don't appear to be supported, it is a reduced set instead.

https://nx.dev/packages/linter/executors/eslint#options-playground

```bash
Options:
  --eslintConfig          The name of the ESLint configuration file.
  --lintFilePatterns      One or more files/dirs/globs to pass directly to ESLint's lintFiles() method. (default: )
  --format                ESLint Output formatter (https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/formatters). (default: stylish)
  --force                 Succeeds even if there was linting errors.
  --silent                Hide output text.
  --fix                   Fixes linting errors (may overwrite linted files).
  --cache                 Only check changed files.
  --cacheLocation         Path to the cache file or directory.
  --outputFile            File to write report to.
  --maxWarnings           Number of warnings to trigger nonzero exit code - default: -1 (default: -1)
  --quiet                 Report errors only - default: false
  --ignorePath            The path of the .eslintignore file.
  --noEslintrc            The equivalent of the --no-eslintrc flag on the ESLint CLI, it is false by default
  --hasTypeAwareRules     When set to true, the linter will invalidate its cache when any of its dependencies changes.
  --skip-nx-cache         Skip the use of Nx cache.
  --help                  Show available options for project target.
```

Some arguments like `reportUnusedDisableDirectives` I was able to add to the *.eslintrc.json* file, but I can't see how to get `--no-error-on-unmatched-pattern`/`noErrorOnUnmatchedPattern` working...